# Delphi + mySQL + Rave Raport

Tags: mysql, delphi, ravereport

Целый месяц бьюсь с реализацией отчёта по средствам ADOQuery и Rave Raport.
С горем пополам, создал отчёт в Rave Raport. Всё заработало! Нажимаем F9 и душа радуется.
Вот он! Вот он отчёт моей мечты! Здоровенный!
Всё вроде хорошо. НО!
Далее, в Delphi делаю кнопку "сформировать отчёт"

```
  RvProject1.SelectReport('Report1',true);
  RvProject1.Open;
  RvProject1.Execute;
  RvProject1.Close;
```

Все компоненты необходимые для реализации отчёта из Delphi на форму брошены и настроены.
(RvProject1, RvSystem1, RvDataSetConnection1).
Т.е. если форма обычная, то она открывается и данные в param через Delphi в неё передаются, всё отображается.

Но если отчёт с DriverDataView1 (это компонент Rave Raport), который внутри себя делает выборку по средствам mySQL-запроса, то с таким отчётом Delphi выдаёт ошибку (см.Картинку)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Одним словом Delphi ругается на несовместимость всех полей присутствующих в той выборке из RaveRaport.
**Вопрос:** как открыть отчёт (который отлажен по SQL-запросу в RaveRaport) из Delphi?
Почему Delphi начал ругаться на поля?
И при чём тут поле формата dtBlob(откуда вообще такое берётся?), когда поля в БД varchar?

Comment: Может быть когда вы создавали отчет/формировали список филдов - в базе был тип Блоб/Текст. Вы потом изменили тип, а старые данные в Delphi остались.

Comment: @androschuk, Нет, наоборот. Были они `text`, но DriverDataView1 видел лишь поля `varchar`. Я заменил на `varchar` и Rave Raport увидел и сформировал. И чуть позже я начал делать кнопку по выводу отчёта из Delphi-приложения.